# Matplotlib 2d histogram with statistics

Tags: matplotlib, statistics, histogram2d

Is there an easy way to provide some basic statistics (RMS for x and y, total number of items etc.) in a legend, like ROOT does:

[image: 2D histogram created with ROOT]

or should I calculate those values manually and add a textbox? How would I do that, since annotating with text needs many styling options and seems way too complicated for such a simple thing…

Comment: Since that is quite a specific task, I'm afraid you have to do it manually. For your convenience, you might wanna use the `table` function described here: http://matplotlib.org/1.2.0/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.table

Comment: If you do write it up it might be worth adding this as a standard plotting tool in `axes`.  Ping me out-of-band if you want help with getting it ready to submit.